# How to write the content Line by Line in a file using java

Tags: java, filewriter, fileoutputstream

How do i write all the ouputs line by line in a txt file? the below snippet is writing only 1 line. Basically i want random_no to be written line by line in txt file.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    HashSet <Integer> newset = new HashSet <Integer>();
    
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        double d=Math.random()*10000;  
        //System.out.println(d);
        String random_no= Integer.toString((int)d);
        newset.add((int)d));
        
        fo = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Test\\Files\\Test_No.txt" ); 
        fo.write(random_no.getBytes();
        
        
        
    }
    fo.close();
    System.out.println("Size is : " +newset.size());
```

Comment: If you want to write text files, you should use a class that implements `Writer`, such as `FileWriter`, as that one accepts strings and `char` values instead of just `byte[]`). That means you don't need to call `getBytes()` on the `Stirng` objects you want to write yourself.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion. Will  it be faster if i use FileWriter instead of FileoutputStream/BufferedWriter? Specially when i need to write large no of rows..more than 10000?

Comment: No, speed will be almost identical. Buffereing (via `BufferedWriter` or `BufferedOutputWriter`) could influence the speed, but that can be applied to either `OutputStream` or `Writer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to do two things:

a) Open file outside the loop

b) Write newline after every number

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test_No.txt");
         HashSet<Integer> newset = new HashSet <Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            double d = Math.random() * 10000;
            // System.out.println(d);
            String random_no = Integer.toString((int) d);
            newset.add((int)d);
            fo.write(random_no.getBytes());
            fo.write("\n".getBytes());
        }
        fo.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file inside the loop, try:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    HashSet <Integer> newset = new HashSet <Integer>();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Test\\Files\\Test_No.txt" );
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        double d=Math.random()*10000;  
        //System.out.println(d);
        String random_no= Integer.toString((int)d) + System.lineSeparator();
        newset.add((int)d);
        fo.write(random_no.getBytes());
    }
    fo.close();
    System.out.println("Size is : " +newset.size());
}
```

You might also want to consider handling the close automatically:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    HashSet <Integer> newset = new HashSet <Integer>();
    try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Test\\Files\\Test_No.txt" )) {
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
            double d=Math.random()*10000;  
            //System.out.println(d);
            String random_no= Integer.toString((int)d) + System.lineSeparator();
            newset.add((int)d);
            fo.write(random_no.getBytes());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Size is : " +newset.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing Andy. It writes all the contents inside the file but not in a line by line format. Is there  any way to format that?

Comment: @Cris-123 you'll need to add in the newline characters, so String random_no= Integer.toString((int)d) + "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

`FileOutputStream` should be initialised outside the loop.

Also, to print new line, you can also use `BufferedWriter` instead of `FileOutputStream`.

`BufferedWriter` gives you option of `BufferedWriter.newLine()` which would handle new lines independent of the environment(windows, unix, etc.).

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        HashSet<Integer> newset = new HashSet<>();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Test_No.txt", true));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            double d = Math.random() * 10000;
            String random_no = Integer.toString((int) d);
            newset.add((int) d);
            bufferedWriter.write(random_no);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Size is : " + newset.size());
    }
```